# Represent "objects' field of view"

Tags: texturing, camera, depth-of-field

I have the following scenario: a model placed on the center and a plane beneath it.

[image]

There is also a top view camera. When rendering:

[image]

I have created four spherical gradients that depend on the distance to four certain objects. My final goal is to create those gradients but limited to the zones the objects "see". For instance, if the model is a cube and there is an object attached to one if its side faces the gradient should not be represented on the opposite face plane part because the object only "sees" what is in front of the face it is placed on.

[image]

On the picture above, the purple point is the object (can be thought of as a camera). As can be seen, there are two gradient areas with red crosses on them that I would like to delete because they are not within the field of view of the object.

Thanks

Comment: I don’t really understand what or why you’re trying to achieve but could you not just swap things around and replace the ‘object’ that you’re wanting to measure its field of view with a lamp and then simply see how that light illuminates the scene. If you set the number of bounces (in cycles) to 0 then you won’t get any diffuse or reflected light bouncing around corners so anything illuminated is within view of the object.

Comment: My final goal is to create a pixel density map using gradients. I would like to know what amount of pixels/m can a camera see within its field of view without taking into account lens distortion. I do not know if it is even possible to do in blender.